# Paste rich text from Google Docs into Thunderbird. How to change the Image handling?

Tags: thunderbird, copy-paste, attachments, embedding

I'm preparing a quotation for a client. I'm doing it on a Google Docs using rich text (colors, bold, list-items, images, etc.) to later copy-paste it into an email composed in Mozilla Thunderbird.

When I copy/paste, all the images are "bound" to some sort of `googleusercontent.com` domain. **But I want the images to be "included" in the email, not linked to the web.**

### Current solution

After pasting, I have to double click image by image, go to the popup, click "attach this image", save.

[image: Attach this image]

This is a time-killer + error-prone method.

## Questions

1. Is there a way to tell the email composer "I want to attach all the images when pasting"?
2. If possible, is there a way to do not change a general setting but only behave lilke this "for this specific email I'm composing in this window"?

Thanks!

Comment: When you copy/paste, it's just copying the HTML image element from google docs. Perhaps google docs is not the best tool for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it.

Setting to change found here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1183434

I'm describing as an answer the full process:

## Step 1: Open the settings

- Click the burger icon
- Find "Settings" and click there

[image: Open thunderbird settings]

## Step 2: Expand the settings

- In the general tab, expand the settings with the last button "Config editor..."

[image: Expand thunderbird settings]

## Step 3: Change the setting

- In the advanced preferences editor search for the preference name
- The initial set is blank. Once you start typing 2 or 3 letters a subset matching appears.
- As soon as you type in, the set is reduced.
- Find **`mail.compose.attach_http_images`**
- Even before you type it completely you'll find it in the list.
- You'll see "false" in the value and it will not be displayed in bold.
- Double click it to change the setting.
- Now it'll say "true" and it'll be in bold to identify the setting has been changed from the default.

[image: Change the setting]

From now on the very same operation will work fine: Just "paste" the HTML and the images will not "point to the external resourced" but will be inlined by default.

You can check that pasting anything in a new message and then double-clicking the image.